# Getting a PgConnection from a Pool with Vert.x vertx-pg-client

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, vert.x

I want to perform an expensive query on postgresql (runtime about 7-60 seconds), occasionally the results aren't needed after the query starts and so I'd like to cancel it. I want to use vert.x libraries to do this. I've looked at using `io.vertx.reactivex.pgclient.PgConnection` as it supports cancelling a query. However there doesn't appear to be a way to get a `PgConnection` from a pooled source. The other option is to use `io.vertx.reactivex.sqlclient.SqlConnection` returned from a `PgPool` but this doesn't support cancelling a query. Thus my question is how can I cancel a query on a pooled connection?

Comment: The `PgPool` while extending `Pool` does not offer specify `PgConnection` support (yet) but will certainly return an instance of it. So you should be able to cast to `PgConnection` and perform cancellation.

Comment: I think this is only true with the non-Rxified version of the PgPool.

Answer (score 0):

```
pgPool.rxGetConnection().flatMap(
    conn -> {
      PgConnection pgconn = new PgConnection((io.vertx.pgclient.PgConnection)conn.getDelegate());
      ...
      return Single.just(conn);
    }
).subscribe(conn -> conn.close());
```

Doing something like the above will give you a `io.vertx.reactivex.pgclient.PgConnection` from the `io.vertx.reactivex.sqlclient.SqlConnection` obtained from a `rxGetConnection`